# Polynomial Congruences

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Prove that if $f(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_n$ and $m$ is an integer, then $k!|f^{(k)}(m)$ where $f^{(k)}$ is the $k^{th}$ derivative of $f$.
I do not know where to even begin this problem

Comment: Can you write an expression for $f^{(k)}(x)$?

Comment: **Hint** $f'(x)=na_0x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_{n-1}.$ And you can use induction.

Comment: A comment: It is slightly more natural to write $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$. In particular because you may show that $$f^{k}(0)=k!a_k$$

Comment: Plus 1 to the above comment. Why would anyone write $a_ox^n+\ldots +a_n$?

Comment: @GitGud I am trying to find a reason.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The $k$th derivative of $x^j$ is $j(j-1)\cdots(j-k+1)x^{j-k}$. If you divide the coefficient by $k!$, can you recognize the expression as a combinatorial quantity that counts something, hence is an integer?

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what to do based on what you are saying